# Installation causing error

Tags: centos, ip, wlan, messaging

I have downloaded g2ipmsg from  http://www.ipmsg.org/archive/g2ipmsg-0.9.6.tar.gz

While installing this package, it is causing some error.

```
 checking for G2IPMSG... configure: error: Package requirements (libgnomeui-2.0 >= 2.14
                gtk+-2.0 >= 2.4
                glib-2.0 >= 2.8) were not met:

    No package 'libgnomeui-2.0' found

    Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
    installed software in a non-standard prefix.

    Alternatively, you may set the environment variables G2IPMSG_CFLAGS
    and G2IPMSG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
    See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

How to resolve this error please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have the package `libgnomeui-2.0` mentionned into the error message correctly installed. Depending of your distribution, use `apt-get` or `yum` to install it.
You may also need to install `gtk+-2.0` and `glib-2.0` (install first package and check the updated error message if any).

Comment: As he is running a `configure` to compile from source, he also needs to install the development counterpart of each of the package you mention. In Ubuntu, `libgnomeui-dev`, `libgtk-3-dev` and `libglib2.0-dev`. In Centos / RedHat, the packages will have `-devel` in the name.

Comment: can you give me the link where i can get and download pls

Comment: There is a tool in Linux that allows you to download packages like this. It is `apt-get` for debian and `yum` for red hat. I see in another question of you that you are using CentOS which is Red Hat based. Then connect with root access rights and make `yum install <package name>` to install the mentioned packages.

Comment: I installed `libgnomeui-devel` by using `yum install libgnomeui-devel` it installed works fine. After installing i ran `./configure` but it showing some error like `No package 'libpanelapplet-2.0' found`

Comment: `[root@localhost Admin]# yum install libglib2.0-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.aol.in
 * epel: mirrors.ispros.com.bd
 * extras: centos.aol.in
 * jpackage-generic: mirror.ibcp.fr
 * jpackage-generic-updates: mirror.ibcp.fr
 * updates: centos.aol.in
Setting up Install Process
No package libglib2.0-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: That message means that a package is missing on your Linux platform. Each time you have this message, install the missing package via `yum install`.

Comment: `[root@localhost Admin]# yum install libgtk-3-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.aol.in
 * epel: mirrors.ispros.com.bd
 * extras: centos.aol.in
 * jpackage-generic: mirror.ibcp.fr
 * jpackage-generic-updates: mirror.ibcp.fr
 * updates: centos.aol.in
Setting up Install Process
No package libgtk-3-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: installed successfully